# Gmail Addon saving form input before initiating authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I want to save a form input before initiating the authorization.

```
export function authCard() {
  const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(CardService.newImage()
        .setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL)
      )
      .addWidget(CardService.newImage()
        .setAltText(BUTTONS.LOGIN.NAME)
        .setImageUrl(BUTTONS.LOGIN.URL)
        .setAuthorizationAction(CardService.newAuthorizationAction()
          .setAuthorizationUrl(getOAuthService().getAuthorizationUrl())
        )
      )
    );

  return card.build();
}
```

I have tried to change the `setAuthorizationAction` to:

```
.setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
  .setFunctionName('actionSubmit')
)

export function actionSubmit(event: any) {
  const region = event.formInput;

  // save this region to a cache
  // return authorization similar to setAuthorizationAction
}
```

How to return and initiate the authorization?

Comment: Are you trying to save the credentials before the login attempt?

Comment: @AMolina nope I'm trying to save a region from a user.